# How to Build the MySQL plugin for Qt Using MySQL Server 8.0?

Tags: c++, sql, windows, qt

I'm new to QT. I tried to Installing QMYSQL driver by using MySQL Server8.0. But I'm unable to build the MySQL plugin for Qt. I tried many ways and thats thing does not help to me.

I used this way

```
C:\Qt\5.14.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include"MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/ib64"
```

to build the MYSQL plugin to QT .

The results like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way to do that, I hope you are using this web-page https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows

First of all, fix your command:

1. add space before MYSQL_LIBDIR
2. change "ib64" to "lib64"
3. make sure all those paths are valid

   C:\Qt\5.14.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/lib64"

Comment: Yes. I've use that website. And try after fix command. However it's got same results. Can u explain how can i sure paths are valid?

Comment: Just open your file navigator and go to this folder "C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/", then check out files inside the "include" and "lib64" folders

Comment: Yes They have files.

Comment: When I run the command " config.log " it show this error                         > compilation terminated.
> mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:448: main.o] Error 1
 => source failed verification.
Trying source 1 (type sybaseEnv) of library tds ...
  => source failed condition '!config.win32'.
test config.sqldrivers.libraries.tds FAILED

Comment: take a look at this article, I hope you find an answer there https://forum.qt.io/topic/96506/qtdriver-not-load/4

Comment: It does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Error was my command. 
`C:\Qt\5.14.2\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/include"MYSQL_LIBDIR="C:/Program Files/MySQL/Connector C++ 8.0/ib64"`
in here it should not be Connector C++/path/ should be the MySQL Server8.0/path/. It should be the path for mysql.h file and libmysql.lib/libmysql.dll.