# How can QMYSQL driver be loaded?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qsqldatabase

In [How to solve "QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973048/qt-qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-windows), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67642478/17726418) says that *libqsqlmysql.a* and *libqsqlmysqld.a* files should exist in `<QtDir>\mingw73_xx\lib` folder.

But I cannot get *libqsqlmysql.a* and *libqsqlmysqld.a* of any place such as GitHub. I only found *libqsqlmysql.dll* and *libqsqlmysqld.dll* files.

Code:

```cpp
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");

db.setDatabaseName("C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data/world/city.idb");

db.setHostName("localhost");

db.setUserName("root");

db.setPassword("1234567890");
```

The output:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QODBC QPSQL
```

Comment: The instructions to build the driver should be similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996316/how-to-build-the-mysql-plugin-for-qt-using-mysql-server-8-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996316/how-to-build-the-mysql-plugin-for-qt-using-mysql-server-8-0)

Comment: why QMYSQL driver not loaded but the available drivers have QMYSQL ,.......

Comment: You probably downloaded drivers that are not compatible with your installed Qt

Comment: my qt ver is 6.5.2. and my mysql ver is 8.0.35 but i dont know where is the qmysql driver is better to download

Comment: wen download 6.5.2 the output  is  QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMARIADB QMYSQL QODBC QPSQL but wen download 6.6.1 output is to with out QMYSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved !
download  from https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases
copy

> **`libcrypto-3-x64.dll , libmysql.dll ,libssl-3-x64.dll`**

to <Qt Dir>\mingw_64\bin
and

> **`qsqlmysqld.dll , qsqlmysql.dll`**

to  <Qt Dir>\mingw_64\plugins\sqldrivers .
 **`The important point is that I was only able to create the program with msvc and could not create my program with mingw.`**